# Why is Delta Function Not in Same Equivalence Class as $f(x) = 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, equivalence-relations, dirac-delta

In ["Measure and Integration" by Dietmar A. Salamon](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/measure.pdf), P4, the author states:
"... it is often convenient to identify two measurable functions if they agree almost everywhere, i.e. on the complement of a set of measure zero. This defines an equivalence relation."

In ["Generalized Functions" V.1, by Gel'Fand and Shilov](https://books.google.com/booksid=dgnjBQAAQBAJ), P5,
the authors state (regarding the Dirac Delta Function $\delta (x - x_1)$: "The singular function $\delta (x - x_1)$ vanishes in a neighborhood of every point $x_0 \neq x_1$". So, $\delta (x)$ vanishes for all x, except on a single interval of measure zero.

In Rigged Hilbert Space theory, as described in ["Generalized Functions" V.2 by Gel'Fand and Shilov](https://books.google.com/books?id=iMo3BQAAQBAJ), there is a linear topological space $\Phi'$ and $\delta (x) \in \Phi'$. $\Phi'$ is also the conjugate to the Schwartz ($S$) space ($\Phi$). Both are countably normed (but not normed) and $\Phi \subset \Phi'$. $\delta (x)$ operates on functions in $\Phi$

Therefore, in $\Phi'$ isn't $\delta (x)$ in the same equivalence class as $f(x) = 0$? I know that cannot be because the two integrate differently with $\Phi$ test functions but, by the above definition of equivalence relation and the fact that the delta function vanishes at all x except on an interval of measure $0$, it looks like one could say that $\delta (x)$ is in the same equivalence class as f(x) = 0 in $\Phi'$. Please show me what I am overlooking.

Comment: Salamon is probably just using a definition of "function" that excludes delta functions and the like; the term "delta function" appears only once in his 300-page monograph.

Comment: Two measurable functions which agree almost everywhere induce the same distribution, which is one reason why they can be considered the same. For $\delta$ and $0$, they induce different distributions.

Comment: @Sangchui Lee But $\delta$ and 0 agree almost everywhere, so if that induces the same distribution, then they induce the same distribution?

Comment: @ConnorHarris So, Salamon's definition of equivalence class which (which I have also seen elsewhere), only applies to regular and not singular functions?

Comment: Given that the point of defining the equivalence class is to simplify integration, I would imagine so. You could include singular functions if you wanted, but you couldn't consider them equivalent to their equivalents with the singularities removed.

Answer (score 2):

The Dirac delta is not a function, it is a distribution.

Comment: In a Hilbert space, the elements are equivalence classes as described by Salamon. Distributions are functionals and "regular" functionals (not singular ones, such as Delta function) can be elements of Hilbert Space (Gel'Fand, Generalized Functions V4 P. 58). Delta is in a countably normed space, that is the conjugate to the Schwartz space, also countably normed. Maybe equivalent classes, as Salamon describes, are not defined for countably normed spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer — because the delta function isn't actually a function, i.e. it's not a function on $\mathbb{R}$. People often informally think of it as a function, but it isn't. Even writing it as "$\delta(x)$" is a nod to this heuristic informal point of view, but it's not actually meaningful. It's a generalized function, a.k.a. a distribution.

So in a space of functions on the real line, be it all measurable functions or bounded or whatnot, we can't even pose the question of whether $\delta(x)$ and $f(x)=0$ are in the same equivalence class — because the delta function isn't even an element of any such space at all.

And in the space of distributions $\Phi'$, they are distinct because they clearly define different linear functionals. Note that $\Phi\subset\Phi'$, and it's a strict inclusion. $f(x)=0$ is an element of $\Phi'$ that comes from $\Phi$, but $\delta(x)$ does **NOT** come from $\Phi$.

Comment: So, elements of Hilbert spaces are equivalence classes as defined by Salamon. $\Phi'$ is not a Hilbert space. Are the elements of $\Phi'$ not equivalence classes as defined by Salamon? Per Gel'Fand, we have $\Phi \in ... \Phi_n...\in...\Phi_0...\in...\Phi'_n...\Phi'$ where $\Phi_n$ and $\Phi'_n$ are Hilbert spaces and the 'n spaces are spaces of functionals that act on the n spaces.

Comment: I guess, upon further thought, I could sum up the responses as: The delta function is not a representative of an equivalence class, a la Salamon, because it is not pointwise defined. It is also not an equivalence class, itself, because there are no pointwise functions that could make up such a class.